# NextJs Redirect to another page after login and other checks

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redirect, next.js

I have a nextJs program, and I'd like to do some checks after the user log in.

Here's the breakdown of what I want to get done. When a user creates an account, and verifies they can log in. After login I want to redirect them to a page where they can set their name, if they decide to close the page or navigate away, I want always to redirect them back to that page until they have their name set. I'm currently on the login page, doing the checks after the user sign into the account, if they don't have a first name, I'm pushing them to the page to enter their name. But so far, if the user clicks away or even closes the page, they are not redirected back. So I want to kinda set a global check on each page, after a user creates an account, I want to always redirect them to enter their name.

```
if (response.code === 200) {
  // user is logged in...
  toast.success("You're logged in!", toastOptions);
  // close the login modal
  dispatch(loginUser(response.data as LoginResponse["data"]));

  // if the user login, we check if he has a first name set,
  // if no first name, we redirect to the register flow to set one.
  try {
    const res = await getUserProfileService(username, token);
    if (
      res.code === 200 &&
      !res.data.first_name.trim() // we need to trim cuz there's a space in the first_name's string in the DB
    ) {
      router.push({
        pathname: "/account/settings-flow",
        query: { token },
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    // if an error occured, we also wants to log the user out.
    const payload = {
      email: emailId,
      session_id: sessionId,
    };
    const res = await logoutService(payload);
    if (res.code === 200) {
      dispatch(logoutUser());
      dispatch(resetUser());
      router.push("/");
      toast.warning("We had to log you out, please login again.", toastOptions);
    }
  }
}
```

Please note that I'm using react/nextJs/ typescript. I just need a way to move this out of this login component and do a global check.